# Get images from all folders that are in another folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, directory

I need to get all my **images** to display on a Gallery page but i don't know how to get the images from the sub folders because they all have different names e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6 for the id of the article that they are in.

Comment: this is where you need to use a database to store the metadata and filesystem location of the images and relate them back to your articles, and not use some weird directory/subdirectory mapping system.

Comment: Agreed with @user1666620 but that unfortunately doesn't solve your problem right now. Suggest you look up https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=c-sharp+walk+directory for help with your current issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just on a quick search i got

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.bmp",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

All you need to do is edit it and add the different types your immages could be

Answer (score 1):

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/images");
private string[] imgFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png")
                                 .Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path))
                                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: this is a crutch for a bad design, but looks like it should work.